# AngularJS - $filter not in global scope

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-scope, angularjs-filter

I am trying to write a unit test for a filter I wrote in Angular (1.0.7).
This filter is working on the actual page, so I know it is getting registered correctly.
But I want to write a unit test for it.

```
var application = angular.module('Customer', []);    
application.filter('date', function () {
    return function (date) {
        return moment(date).format('MM/DD/YYYY');
    };
});
```

At the top of the test page, I include the angular.js file.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../angular.js"></script>
```

Supposedly, there is a `$filter` function for retrieving registered filters.
My debugger just freaks out and says it's not there. I can see the actual `angular` variable, so I know angular is being included correctly.

I am wondering if I am missing a .js file or if the `$filter` is in a different scope or a newer version of angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `$filter('date')` to get the `date` filter by injecting the `$filter` module before the actually test stub. I created a working demo for you and please take a look at the required JS files.

```
describe('date', function () {
    var dataFilter;
    beforeEach(angular.mock.module('Customer'));

    beforeEach(function () {
        angular.mock.inject(function ($filter) {
            dataFilter = $filter('date');
        })
    });

    describe('date result', function () {
        it('should return filtered date', function () {
            var date = new Date(2013, 7, 15);
            expect(dataFilter(date)).toBe('08/15/2013');
        });
    });
});
```

<kbd>**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/X5cfp/)**</kbd>

Comment: Do I need the resource .js file in order for `angular.mock.module` to appear?

Comment: @TravisParks You don't need that. :) I was including that for something else I tried.

Comment: Okay. I was having an issue earlier where `module` wasn't found under `angular.mock` for some reason. I'll try again.

Comment: A little poking around, it looks like `angular.mock.module` only exists if you're using Jasmine. I am using Mocha with Chai's expect.

Comment: There is support for Mocha after the 1.1.1 release, but it is not part of a stable build release yet. I think I will just switch over to Jasmine... they're almost identical, honestly.

Comment: @TravisParks I have used Mocha for my node.js apps with another module called `should`, the syntax looks good though.